# Listing usb devices using pyusb doesn't work

Tags: python, pyusb

I am trying to list USB devices on my windows 7 pc. I installed this ahead: https://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb-win32/files/libusb-win32-releases/1.2.6.0/libusb-win32-devel-filter-1.2.6.0.exe

The code below does not print anything. Is there something else to be done to get the device info?

```
import usb.core
import usb.util
dev = usb.core.find(find_all=True)
for d in dev:
    print(usb.util.get_string(d,128,d.iManufacturer))
```

Edit: Solved

This comes close to what I need 
[Retrieve list of USB items using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41959775/retrieve-list-of-usb-items-using-python)

```
import win32com.client
wmi = win32com.client.GetObject ("winmgmts:")
for usb in wmi.InstancesOf ("Win32_USBHub"):
    print('Device ID:', usb.DeviceID)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using a Python libusb wrapper. This will only enumerate USB devices which have actually been associated with the libusb driver. Every device is associated with a driver, and most will have class drivers (eg HID, UVC, MSC, etc) provided by the OS, so you need to use a different API to access them. You can enumerate all devices in a generic fashion by using the native SetupAPI and WinUSB on Windows, if that's what you really want. But this wrapper will only enumerate devices that specifically use the libusb driver. Since your code doesn't show any, you probably just don't have a device that uses libusb.

You can use the Zadig tool to remap drivers to different devices. But beware of doing this as you can easily break things if you happen to choose an unsupported configuration. It's normally used when you have a custom or 3rd party device.

Comment: gavinb is spot on. If you're lucky, your device presents itself as a serial port and you can find it with pyserial. If not, maybe you have to do operating system API calls through pywin.